# Is there an easy way to check if some instance is FunctionX in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

Is there any less verbose solution than the solution shown below to check if an instance is Function0/Function1...?

```
 def isFunction(x: Any) = x match {
        case x: Function0[_] => true
        case x: Function1[_,_] => true
        case x: Function2[_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function3[_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function4[_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function5[_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function6[_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function7[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function8[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function9[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function10[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function11[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function12[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function13[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function14[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function15[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function16[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function17[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function18[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function19[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function20[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function21[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case x: Function22[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] => true
        case _ => false
  }


  val x = () => 4

  println(isFunction(x))
```

Comment: I definitely think that is the "easy" way, although it might be more verbose than you would like. However, there is no base class you can test for, nor any other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You mean given:

```
scala> val f = (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j
f: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

you want to say

```
scala> val r = "scala.*Function\\d+".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*Function\d+

scala> def test(a: Any): Boolean = { def t(k: Class[_]): Boolean = k.getName match { case r() => true case _ => if (k.getSuperclass != null) t(k.getSuperclass) else false } ; t(a.getClass) }
test: (a: Any)Boolean

scala> test(f)
res1: Boolean = true
```

?

That is on a par with the [Tuple test](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L37).

Comment: Well... But my concern about this solution is the performance!

Comment: Well, naturally, but your user story was "less verbose."  Maybe full Java 8 support will help in future. It's also possible that performance wouldn't be orders off.